# Is there a matrix whose sum with the canonical Mixing Hamiltonian in Qaoa is proportional to the identity matrix?

Tags: pauli-gates, qaoa, linear-algebra

Does there exist a Hermitian matrix, $K$ s.t $B^\prime = B + K$ satisfies $(B^\prime)^2 = c\cdot I$, where $B = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma_x^{(i)}$, $\sigma_x^{(i)}$ is the Pauli X matrix acting on qubit $i$, $I$ is the identity matrix and $c \in \mathcal{R}$.

If so, what is $K$ and what is the commutative relationship with $B$? Can we have $K$ that commutes with $B$?

For $n=1$, $K=\sigma_x$, $c=4$ and $[K, B] = 0$.

Comment: I don't think your $n=2$ example satisfies $(B + K)^2 \propto I$, i.e. $(X_0 + X_1 + I + Y_0 Y_1 + Z_0 Z_1)^2 \neq c I$

Comment: Is $B=\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_x$ which equals $n\sigma_x$ a notation mistake?

Comment: Yes, not only was the notation incorrect, I realize that the relationship was incorrect as @forky40 mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just pick $K=I-B$. It is hermitian, $B'=B+K=I$ and thus $(B')^2=I$, and $K$ commutes with $B$.

Comment: Thanks @Norbert Schuch!